# Basic Dialog Box in Java

Tags: java, dialog, switch-statement, joptionpane

Hello I am working on a school project and I am having trouble displaying a basic dialog box in Java. Basically I need to create an alert saying the Lion has a cut on his left paw. I found the JOptionPane tool which works but it pops up at the beginning of the program. Right now when I run this in Netbeans,the dialog box just pops up, displays the message, and then ends the code. I need this dialog box to appear *after* the user has selected the lion option. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
 package monitoringsystem;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MonitoringSystem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean mainmenu = true;
    while (mainmenu) {
        System.out.println("Select an option");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to Monitor Animals");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to Monitor Habitats");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to exit");
        int Number = input.nextInt();
        switch (Number) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Monitor Animals");
                System.out.println("Select an option");
                System.out.println("Press 1 for Details on Lions ");
                System.out.println("Press 2 for Details on Tigers");
                System.out.println("Press 3 for Details on Bears");
                System.out.println("Press 4 for Details on Giraffes");
                System.out.println("Press 5 to return to Main Menu");
                int animalNum = input.nextInt();
                switch (animalNum) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Animal - Lion");
                        System.out.println("Name: Leo");
                        System.out.println("Age: 5");
                        System.out.println("Feeding schedule: Twice daily\n");
                        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "Health concerns: Cut on front left paw", "Alert",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        break;
```

Comment: Are you limited to using Swing?

Comment: Nope. I just need to create a dialog box.

Comment: You should try *stepping* through this code with a debugger, is it likely that you have the consume the `ENTER` key that you pressed? `input.nextLine` ?

Comment: You should avoid mixing console and GUI, they have different working requirements and flows

Comment: Also, this code does not run; in order to `showInternalMessageDialog`, you need to pass a valid parent, not `null`. You could use `showMessageDialog()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple method of showing a dialog window using JavaFX. You may be able to learn enough from this in order to adapt it for your program?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button btnClickMe = new Button("Click Me!");

        btnClickMe.setOnAction(event -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setHeaderText("The lion has a cut on its paw!");
            alert.setContentText("Run away!!");

            alert.showAndWait();
        });

        root.getChildren().add(btnClickMe);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This may be a bit advanced for you right now, but it DOES show a dialog window!